# Pass external var to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

HTML FILE:

```
<head>
   //include jQuery
</head>
<body>
    //HTML stuff

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var prd = 'something';
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
$('#select span').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;

    var path = '/scripts/test/sqlgetdata.php?id='+id+'&p='+prd;

    path = encodeURIComponent(path);

    post(path);
});

function post(path){
  //stuff
}
```

The `var prd` is not avaiable on the function to include it in `var path`.

I've alse tried:

```
$('#select span').click(function(prd)
```

Is it possible to solve this without a callback?
Thank you

Comment: with the update it should be available

Comment: Consolle says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: prd is not defined`

Comment: @Perocat: Make sure you're including `script.js` *after* your `script` block where `prd` is defined.

Comment: Of course I do, but if I move prd to the external JS file, it goes as global var, but if the var prd is declared on the HTML as I asked then the consolle displays the error. The HTML is exactly as I wrote here

Comment: Which line throws that error? If all the code you have is what you have shown it should work (not in the expected way, but at least it should not show that error).

Comment: Line 4 (where var path is defined) of script.js

Comment: @Perocat Are you sure you are not including `script.js` twice? Do you have an online demo that we can check and shows the problem? Otherwise it seems we cannot solve this "mistery".

Comment: I solved... On the same page I used the swfobject.js script and changing the var name from prd to somethingelse now it works...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's passed to `event.data`

```
$('#select span').click({prd: prd}, function(e){
    var id  = this.id;
    var prd = e.data.prd; // here

    var path = '/scripts/test/sqlgetdata.php?id='+id+'&p='+prd;

    path = encodeURIComponent(path);

    post(path);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wnhL/2/)

Comment: if prd is giving an error saying it is undefined.... I think most probably it will be during the event registration itself

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Nope, `prd` is not accessible inside the event handler when using the eventData method, it's attached to `event.data.prd`, and that's why there's an error in the OP's code.

Comment: if I move prd to the external JS file, it goes as global var, but if the var prd is declared on the HTML then the consolle displays the error

Comment: Well, it should simply use the other `prd` defined in the outer scope in the original code. I guess the error is due to the OP not telling something.

Comment: @kapa - In this case it should, as `prd` is not only the key used, but should also be a variable in a higher scope, but the OP is for some strange reason using the eventData method, and the answer simply shows how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Perocat - What do you mean "declared on HTML", this method doesn't get anything from the DOM ?

Comment: @adeneo I think it is wrong to say a global variable will not be accessible inside a function because the event data has the same key

Comment: I mean declared on a script section on the HTML file and not on the external JS file

Comment: @Perocat It should still work (check the fiddle in my answer), there is something else...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9PyEA/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I didn't say a global variable wasn't accessible, but the OP is clearly using the eventData model for some reason, and it's a neat way to pass data to an event handler, and to access that data you would use event.data and not the global variable.

Comment: The point of eventData is to pass in data that would be locked inside the event handler, see this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wnhL/3/

Comment: @adeneo that was my first point... if `prd` was giving an reference error how does the event handler will get registered since the registration process itself is using `prd`

Comment: Actually, this is a better example -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wnhL/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yes, thats correct, if the variable was undefined the script would fail, and no event handler would be registered -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wnhL/5/

Comment: @adeneo yes... as far as usage goes that is the way to handle it(still based on requirement)... but my question is if `prd` is not defined anywhere it gives an reference error... since op is getting an reference error how will the event registration happens

Comment: @adeneo yes that is what I was meaning... so the problem seems to lying somewhere else

Comment: @ArunPJohny - You are right, from some of the comments above it seems the OP has an issue with defining the variable in a script tag somewhere else, and for some reason it's not available when the event handler is bound, so the issue isn't really the eventData, even if the use of the eventData model is wrong as well.